# Creating a matrix of randomly generated characters

Tags: c, arrays, random, char

I'm trying to create a randomly generated matrix of randomly generated characters;
I can't understand errors made in my code, if someone could higlight them.... probably there are many, since it's my first time with this kind of codes.

I mean, it compiles, but it printes a serie of ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ '-', but the characters created should be alphabetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE_STRING 20

int main() {



    int number_arr_rows= 5;
    int i , j;
    int min_size_string= 4;
    float probability;
    int *arr_string_lenght = (int*)malloc(number_arr_rows*sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++){
        arr_string_lenght[i]= min_size_string + rand() % ( MAX_SIZE_STRING - min_size_string + 1);
    }


    char **created_string_arr = (char**)malloc(number_arr_rows * sizeof(*created_string_arr));
    for( i = 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++){
        created_string_arr[i] = (char*)malloc(arr_string_lenght[i]*sizeof(created_string_arr));
    }


// generating characters [A-Z][a-z] randomly. 50% probability.
    for(i= 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < arr_string_lenght[j] ; j++){
            probability = (float)((rand() % 101) / 100);
            if(probability <= 0.5){
            created_string_arr[i][j]= (char)(65 + rand() %26);
        }

            else{
            created_string_arr[i][j] = (char)(97 +rand() %26);

        }
    } 
}

    for(i = 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < arr_string_lenght[i] ; j++){
            printf("%s\n" , created_string_arr[i]);
        }
    }
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code. `char **` is not a 2D array and cannot represent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first obvious problem is in these lines:

```
for(i= 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++){
    for(j = 0 ; j < arr_string_lenght[j] ; j++){
```

You're using `j` to index into `arr_string_lenght` inside the `j` loop...that should be `i`

Secondly, you don't `NUL` terminate your strings so you can't do this:

```
printf("%s\n" , created_string_arr[i]);
```

And you shouldn't need to since you're looping over every element anyway and that also gets around the problem that you're not allocating enough memory to store the `NUL` anyway. You can just print out each character like this:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < number_arr_rows ; i++) {
    for( j = 0 ; j < arr_string_lenght[i] ; j++) {
        printf("%c" , created_string_arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Also you don't `free` the memory you've allocated. It's good practice to do it even in simple programs like this to firmly embed the habit for larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris's answer:

You will generate the same values everytime because you don't seed the random generator:

```
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
```

before all of usages of `rand()`.
Also you will (almost) always generate upper case values because the expression

```
probability = (float)((rand() % 101) / 100);
```

will evaluate to 0 almost everytime. Instead you should use:

```
probability = ((float)(rand() % 101)) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Don't need to do `srand()` before all uses of `rand()` - just once at the start of the program is enough.